# Is it wrong to use "extra" variables because it's easier for debugging?

Tags: c#

I was just debugging some code that looked like this:

```
string someValue = _snuh.FindItem(id).Value;
```

I wanted to inspect the return value of `FindItem()` (it returns a `Foo`), so I broke the code into two lines:

```
Foo foo = _snuh.FindItem(id);
string someValue = foo.Value;
```

This allowed me to look at foo in the debugger; something I wasn't able to do when the code was all on one line.

Now that I'm done debugging, should I put the code back the way it was, or leave it as two lines?

Comment: I think codereview.stackexchange.com might get you more constructive feedback.

Comment: Your code is wrong either way. What happens if `_snuh.FindItem(id)` returns null? you get an exception and your application crashes down in pieces.

Comment: This is subjective. However, it is a good practice to break things for readability purpose. It would be better if `foo` is used multiple times.

Comment: You found it valuable for debugging (and so do I), and it didn't decrease readability.  I'd leave it.

Comment: Incidentally, the C# compiler suppresses the "local variable is written but not read" warning in similar situations because so many people do this kind of thing to facilitate debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than have a one liner like this

```
string someValue = _snuh.FindItem(id).Value;
```

I would rather *refactor* such that you have

```
string someValue = _snuh.FindItemValue(id);
```

and encapsulate the `FindItem()` and subsequent `Value` dereference in a function.

Why ? Your first solution exposes the implementation of the object returned by `FindItem` (i.e. that it has a `Value` field). The [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) suggests the second variant. Additionally it avoids repetition if you have to do this in many places. If you have to perform a null check you only have to do this *once*.

Comment: +1. I hope this answer doesn't get lost due to all of the other answers. The Law of Demeter is a good point, the code can still be clean (one line), and I can still check that variable since it's now encapsulated in another method. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The two lines are better than the one liner:

- You can debug them
- If you have a null pointer, you will see the line number in your error logs (and see directly what is wrong)
- It is more readable
- No need for extra comments to explain what the one-liner is doing
- There is no difference in performance (the compiler will optimize to the same IL)
- If you rewrite code after debugging it, you can introduce new typos

Comment: +1 for the good reasons listed. I'm having a hard time deciding between your answer and Brian Agnew's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You read your code more than you write it.

Leave it in the shape that you find most readable. JIT will optimize your code anyway.

Comment: +1 for a great point: "You read your code more than you write it." Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

At our workplace our code-style guidelines requires that the result of a method call is stored in a variable. The idea behind this is that if a null-reference exception is thrown, the line number will tell you precisely which variable is null - something that wouldn't be possible if you operated directly on the result of a method.

In practice, this rule is flouted to an extent - particularly when doing Linq queries as Linq methods do not return nulls (the guidelines predate widespread use of Linq).

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, you can use **"immediate window"** or **"add watch"** to debug parts of a statement and see their values without using extra variables.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible in my scenario? There is no variable to check in the immediate window, or in the watch window. I'm not sure how this can be done with no foo variable.

Comment: @BobHorn : Just select `snuh` or `_snuh.FindItem(id)` or `_snuh.FindItem(id).Value`  in `string someValue = _snuh.FindItem(id).Value;` -> right-click -> Add Watch

Comment: +1 Great tip! Only this one worked: `_snuh.FindItem(id)`. And that makes sense because that's the only part that returns the value in which I'm interested in checking. I didn't know you could add a watch for a method call (and watch its return value). Thanks!

Comment: @BobHorn : You should select an answer if you think your question is solved, to increase your acceptance ratio.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would go with the second approach along with having a "NULL" check on the returning object before accessing its "Value" property as it is prone to Null Reference Exception; which would look something like below.

```
string someValue = string.Empty;
Foo foo = _snuh.FindItem(id);
if (foo != null)
{
    someValue = foo.Value;
}
```

Hope this Helps!!